# How can I create the equivalent of an explode(), implode() pattern match approach in Google Sheets using formulas?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Here's my goal:

I have the following data set:

[image]

From that, I'd like to generate the following:

[image: Category Result Set]

In the interest of RTFM, here's my thought process and what I've tried:

Firstly, the top set's two columns are in their own named ranges: Color_Abbrevs, Category_Names, respectively.

I know I can use JOIN() to produce the results in Category Output from the category names like so:

`JOIN("/",Category_Names)`

My challenge now is how to create a sort of "pattern matcher" (I don't know what else to call it) whereby I can use the abbreviations in place of the category names to render the result string.  An example of the desired pattern format is shown in A8:A10.

To start, I tried to think through using something like an INDEX and MATCH approach:

`=INDEX(Category_Names,MATCH(LEFT(A8,FIND("/",A8)-1),Category_Abbrevs,0))`

This yields the correct value in A9, so I thought I might be on the right track.  The part I'm stuck on is how to connect the JOIN and INDEX and MATCH formulas together to allow for a variable length of Abbreviations and Categories.

Ideally, I want to be able to continue adding values to the top data set and define whatever unique "patterns" I need in a list via the second data set to get the desired result.

Is this possible using formulas, or do I need to write some Google script to achieve it?

EDIT: Rows B8 and B9 both have typos (apologies).  B8 should show "Tile Daily Store/Porcelain" and B9 should show "Tile Depot Store/Metallic Porcelain".

Comment: Just for carification: row 9 shows `TDS/MP` but returns "Porcelain Mosaic" instead of "Metallic Porcelain"... also Row 8 only returns the "TDS" and ignores the "PT"... are that typos?

Comment: Yes, indeed.  I've added an EDIT to the post -- thanks for catching that.

Comment: Do you want an excel answer or just Google Sheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively you also can use the formula (at B8):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("/";LOOKUP(SPLIT(A8;"/");$A$2:$A$6;$B$2:$B$6)))
```

in Google Sheets to get the "category output" in the same order like it is at  "structure"

**EDIT**

Looks like I missed something here :P

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("/";VLOOKUP(SPLIT(A8;"/";TRUE);$A$2:$B$6;2;FALSE())))
```

Will do if everything is also in the list (if something is not found, it will completely error out)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("/";IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(A8;"/";TRUE);$A$2:$B$6;2;FALSE());"---")))
```

This will show "---" for each part which was not found...

Comment: When I try to use this one in A8 with the values as shown in the image above, I get "Porcelain Mosaic/Porcelain".  Wondering if I've missed something.

Comment: I've double-checked it... and now it does everything, except the task it should do... I'm confused O.o

Comment: @SteveK If you use the LOOKUP the data being searched must be sorted in ascending order.  Sort it and you will get the correct answer.

Comment: I think I missed something here... since when does that count for strings??? Simply changed it to `VLOOKUP` now (because I am lazy) :P

Comment: Well, now all three of them work, but which should be accepted?!  (Thanks to you both, by the way)

Comment: This simply depends on you... all formulas have their own pros and cons ;)

Comment: FYI, this seems more graceful to me if that makes sense -- or at least, easier for me to comprehend.

Answer (score 2):

In Google Sheets use this formula:

```
=JOIN("/",filter($B$1:$B$6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$6,A8))))
```

[image]

---

In excel, Excel introduced in Office 365 the TEXTJOIN() function, which we can use in an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$6,A8)),$B$1:$B$6,""))
```

Being an array in excel on must use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

**NOTE**

Both these methods will put the output in order of the searched area and not the order in the criteria cell.

Comment: Thanks for this, Scott! I was also presented with the following:

`=IFERROR(JOIN("/",ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT('Data Entry'!$D2,"/",TRUE)),Categories,2,FALSE))),"")`

What are your thoughts on this versus your solution?

(The value I'm splitting is on a sheet "Data Entry", etc)

Comment: @SteveK I don't have an opinion, there are many ways to get to an answer.   I did make one adjustment to the sheets formula.  It is shorter and not an array formula.  Test them all and find which works better for you.

Comment: The main drawback to mine over yours is that mine will put them in order of the list and not the value in A8,A9,A10.  If that is important then I would use yours.